# Running Node JS app like PHP in apache

Tags: node.js, express, server, centos

I have a VPS under CentOS 6.7 and I have the folder public_html in my root directory and I have an express application in a folder called cms.

Right now I have to start my server by going to the the folder where my app is located : public_html/cms then I run the node js server using the command  `node app.js` so my question is : how can I keep my node js app running always like PHP applications in apache? I also what to be able to modify my files using FTP and see the changes taking effect like with normal PHP applications.

Thanks

Comment: I want procedure with details please.

Comment: Does [`pm2 README`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) not work for you?

Comment: http://icomarini.com/blog/post/run-nodejs-in-production-with-apache2